# Unbind click event of an element after first click and rebind it after action perfomed in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a list of items in ng-repeat  and each of them has a delete button. The action of delete button is some ajax request. My problem is if  a user click multiple times on a delete button my api call will get failed because it is deleted in the first click and passing id is not valid in second click . 
I want to unbind  the click after first click and rebind the same  on my ajax request success callback.

Here is what I have tried is

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="labels in addedLabels track by $index">
   {{labels.Label.label_name}}
    <button ng-click="removeLabel(labels.label_id, labels.module_id,$index,true,$event);">
    </button>
</li>
```

**IN CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.removeLabel  = function(label_id,module_id,index,popup,event){
    $(event.currentTarget).off('click')
   opts.url    = SERVER_URL + 'path';
   opts.data   = {
                label_id: label_id,
                module_id : module_id
            };
  $http.post(opts.url,opts.data)
    .then(function(response){
      // some action
     },function(err){
      // error action
     }).finally(function(){
      $(event.currentTarget).on('click')
   })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`disable` Edit button until delete API call respond to either success or failed. Also pass `labels` object to `removeLabel` method, so can easily grab properties from the same.

**Html**

```
<li ng-repeat="labels in addedLabels track by $index">
   {{labels.Label.label_name}}
    <button ng-disabled="labels.disabled" ng-click="removeLabel(labels,$index,true,$event);">
    </button>
</li>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.removeLabel = function(label, module_id, index, popup, event) {
    opts.url = SERVER_URL + 'path';
    opts.data = {
        label_id: label.label_id,
        module_id: label.module_id
    };
  label.disabled = true; //disabling button 
    $http.post(opts.url, opts.data)
      .then(function(response) {
      // some action
    }, function(err) {
      // error action
    }).finally(function() {
      label.disabled = false; //enabling it
    })
}
```

Comment: hello Pankaj, 
I have tried  it. But it deleted the next element also. 
I have clicked first element 2 times, then first and second element get deleted

Comment: @Jennifer something might be wrong with the code that's handling the removal of that label from the array.

Comment: I have edited my question.Code to  remove the  label from array added.
Also when I put my $http request in a $timeout it's working fine. I am not sure what is happened with it